# Why do we need "Algebraic Data Types"?

Tags: scala, haskell, algebraic-data-types

I've read some explanation of Algebraic Data Types:

- [The Algebra of Algebraic Data types I](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/)
- [The Algebra of Algebraic Data types II](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/11/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-part-ii/)
- [The Algebra of Algebraic Data types III](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/13/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types-part-iii/)
- [The Algebra of Data, and Calculus of Mutation](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3011)

These articles give very detail description and code samples.

At first I was thinking Algebraic Data Type was just for defining some types easily and we can match them with pattern matching. But after reading these articles, I found "pattern matching" is not even mentioned there, and the content looks interesting but far more complex than I expected.

So I have some questions (which are not answered in these articles):

- Why do we need it, say, in Haskell or Scala?
- What we can do if we have it, and what we can't do if we don't have it?

Comment: You want tuples to return more than one result and you want sum-types to make the choices you have explicit. (of course this is only the first drop in the ocean - you can write books about this stuff). The link you gave is maybe misleading - you might get the idea that you need this stuff only for ivory-tower-arkane-magic stuff but it's really just a way to manage your data in a sane way (especially if you don't have classes and inheritance and mutating references at your disposal)

Comment: @Carsten I feel you understand what I'm confused with. Appreciated your comment and hope you can tell something more :)

Comment: Just to express the warning that the acronym "ADT" is used also to mean "Abstract Data Type", which is an opposed concept to "Algebraic Data Type". The acronym "ADT" should thus be used with caution, i.e., not at all.

Comment: @pigworker thanks, fixed

Comment: If you want to know why people need numbers, don't start with a course in number theory. It won't mention things like balancing your checkbook or counting sheep. I exagerrate but only a little.

Comment: Coincidentially, I remember a very similar question on another network site with (imho) more exhaustive answers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/287461/what-problem-do-algebraic-data-types-solve

Answer (score 10):

We should start with the Haskell wiki article [*Algebraic Data Types*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type)

And here, shortly, just my vision:

- we need them to model business logic in old object oriented way (or actually in old categories-based way), and make it more typesafe as compiler can check that you've matched all possible choices. Or, in other words, that your function is [total](https://uf-ias-2012.wikispaces.com/file/view/turner.pdf), not partial. Eventually, it gives the compiler an ability to proof the correctness of your code (that's why sealed traits are recommended). So, the more different types you have the better - btw, generic programming helps you here as it produces more types.
- standard features: we can represent type as a "set" of objects, we can match object with type (using pattern matching), or even deconstruct (analyze) it with matchers. We can also dynamically add behavior (in compile-time) to such type with type classess. It's possible for regular class as well, but here it gives us an ability to separate algebraic model (types) from behavior (functions)
- we can construct types as [products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory))/[coproducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) of different objects/types. You can  think of algebraic type system as a set (or more generally - as a cartesian-closed category). `type Boolean = True | False` means that Boolean is a union (coproduct) of `True` and `False`. `Cat(height: Height, weight: Weight)` is a "tuple" (more generally - product) of `Height` and `Weight`. Product (more-less) represents "part of" relationship from OOP, coproduct - "is" (but in the opposite way).

It also gives us a way to dispatch behaviour in runtime in multimethod-style (like it was in [CLOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System)):

```
  sealed trait Animal
  case class Cat extends Animal
  case class Dog extends Animal

 def move(c: Animal) = c match {
   case Cat(...) => ...
   case Dog(...) =>
   case a: Animal => ...//if you need default implementation
 }
```

Haskell-like:

```
 data Animal = Dog | Cat //coproduct

 let move Dog d = ...
 let move Cat c = ...
```

Instead of:

```
trait Animal {
  ...
  def move = ...
}

class Cat(val ...) extends Animal {
  override def move = ...
}

class Dog(val ...) extends Animal {
  override def move = ...
}
```

P.S. Theoretically, if you're modeling the world in algebraic way and your functions are total and pure - you can proof that your application is correct. If it compiles - it works :).

P.S.2. I should also mention that Scala's type hierarchy which has `Any` in it isn't so good for typesafety (but good for interop with Java and IO) as it breaks the nice structure defined by GADTs. More than that `case class` might be both GADT (algebraic) and ADT (abstract) as well, which also reduces the guarantees.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm thinking ADT before reading these articles. But seems they are talking with something different

Comment: I believe, it's actually almost same as you thought except that you can (more-less) think about them as a Sets `data Boolean = True | False` means that Boolean is a union (coproduct) of True and False. Cat(height: Height, weight: Weight) is a product of Height and Weight

Comment: @Freewind I've added some analogies with category theory

Answer (score 3):

The blog post you mention is more about the mathematical aspects of algebraic data types that about their practical use in programming. I think most functional programmers first learnt about algebraic data types by using them in some programming language, and only later studied their algebraic properties.

Indeed, the intent of the blog post is clear from its very beginning:

> In this series of posts I’ll explain why Haskell’s data types are
>   called algebraic - without mentioning category theory or advanced
>   math.

Anyway, the practical usefulness of algebraic types is best appreciated by playing around with them.

Suppose, for instance, you want to write a function to intersect two segments on a plane.

```
def intersect(s1: Segment, s2: Segment): ???
```

What should the result be? It's tempting to write

```
def intersect(s1: Segment, s2: Segment): Point
```

but what if there's no intersection? One might attempt to patch that corner case by returning `null`, or by throwing a `NoIntersection` exception. However, two segments might also overlap on more than one point, when they lie on the same straight line. What should we do in such cases? Throwing another exception?

The algebraic types approach is to design a type covering all the cases:

```scala
sealed trait Intersection
case object NoIntersection extends Intersection
case class SinglePoint(p: Point) extends Intersection
case class SegmentPortion(s: Segment) extends Intersection

def intersect(s1: Segment, s2: Segment): Intersection
```

There are many practical cases where such approach feels quite natural. In some other languages lacking algebraic types, one has to resort to exceptions, to `null`s (also see [the billion-dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#History)), to non-sealed classes (making it impossible for the compiler to check for exhaustiveness of pattern matching), or to other features provided by the language. Arguably, the "best" option in OOP is to use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to encode algebraic types and pattern matching in languages which have no such features. Still, having that directly supported in the language, as in scala, is much more convenient.