# Failure not related to Future?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I’m learning Scala with the official course on Coursera. I’m speaking Java quite fluent, but this is something new. I get a knot in my brain.

The last programming assesment deals with asynchronous programming. I struggle with implementing a method of the companion object:

```
case class WikiResult[A](value: Future[Either[Seq[WikiError], A]])
object WikiResult:
  def successful[A](a: A): WikiResult[A] = WikiResult(Future.successful(Right[Seq[WikiError], A](a)))

  def traverse[A, B](as: Seq[A])(f: A => WikiResult[B])(using ExecutionContext): WikiResult[Seq[B]] =
    as match
      case Seq() => WikiResult.successful(Seq.empty)
      case _ => as.foldLeft(WikiResult.successful(Seq.empty))((wili, a) => {
        val b = f(a)
        b.value match
          case Failure(_) => WikiResult.successful(Seq.empty)
          case _ => WikiResult.successful(Seq.empty)
      })
```

This of course is no complete solution but a try to get the syntax right.

If the given `as` is empty, i return a new `WikiResult` with an empty `value` sequence.

Else, i iterate over `as` (as hinted in the task) with `foldleft()`. For each value `a` in `as`, i call the given function `f`. `b.value` can have three different states: `Success(Right(val: B))` if everything worked, `Success(Left(errlist: Seq[WikiError]))` if a domain error happened, or `Failure(exc: WikiException)` if a system failure occured.

ATM, i’m testing only for the last case. To avoid incompleteness, i add the generic case. In both cases, i simply return an empty result.

To my big surprise, i get `this case is unreachable since type concurrent.Future[Either[Seq[wikigraph.errors.WikiError], B]] and class Failure are unrelated`. Whereever i read about scala´s `Future`, i found that matches are done with `Success` and `Failure`. I cannot imagine what i did wrong?

IDE is IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. Scala and JVM are provided by IDE.

I found a lot of "case unreachable" questions but none correlated to my problem.

Any hints?

TIA
QNo

Comment: What is the definition of `WikiResult`? BTW `Future` and `Failure` are indeed unrelated, `Failure` is a subtype of `Try` not of `Future`. However, `Future` does use `Try` under the hood, so you probably saw the use of `Failure` when calling certain methods on `Future` like `transform`

Comment: Could you make your code self-contained? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/c798BQMPT4iQHLEB8u30QQ [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez i edited my text so that you can find the class definition more easily.

Comment: @DmytroMitin i tried. Better?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah ok. After rereading i think i understand that Success/Failure are availible after a callback. Is that correct?

Comment: You want to use `b.value.transformWith` rather than pattern matching there.

Answer (score 3):

There are methods `Future.successful(...)` and `Future.failed(...)`.

But it's [`Try`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala) that is an [ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759736/why-do-we-need-algebraic-data-types) with two cases `Success` and `Failure`, not [`Future`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala)

```scala
sealed abstract class Try[+T] extends Product with Serializable
final case class Success[+T](value: T) extends Try[T]
final case class Failure[+T](exception: Throwable) extends Try[T]
```

There is `.value` that transforms a future into `Option[Try[T]]`. The thing is that at current moment a future is not necessarily successful or failed, maybe it's not completed yet.

If you want "to get `T` from `Future[T]`" then you can block with [`Await.result`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/package.scala#L199) or register a callback with `future.onComplete(...)`. Or you can keep working with `Future`s. By the way, there is `Future.traverse`.

Using [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/),

```scala
import cats.data.Nested
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

trait WikiError

case class WikiResult[A](value: Future[Either[Seq[WikiError], A]])
object WikiResult:
  def successful[A](a: A): WikiResult[A] = WikiResult(Future.successful(Right[Seq[WikiError], A](a)))

  def traverse[A, B](as: Seq[A])(f: A => WikiResult[B])(using ExecutionContext): WikiResult[Seq[B]] =
    WikiResult(as.traverse(a => Nested(f(a).value)).value)
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/c798BQMPT4iQHLEB8u30QQ/6